# software update microsoft visual studio 2008 sp1 failed hash value incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-2008, service-pack

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2008 sp1 and at the end it returns an error saying "The hash value is not correct". Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by downloading .iso file instead of .exe file