# "Hash Value" error when installing Visual Studio 2008 sp

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2008 sp and at the end it returns an error saying "The hash value is not correct".

Comment: Is it just the service pack that you're trying to install?  What version of Windows are you running?  Do you have other versions of Visual Studio installed?  Are there any further details in the error?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612443/software-update-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-sp1-failed-hash-value-incorrect Download the iso instead of the exe

Comment: @Taegost windows 7 yes two version 2010 and 2008 no further details in the error

Comment: You can try Ocaso's suggestion and see if that helps.  I know that VS is *very* finicky about the order things are installed.  You may need to uninstall all versions of VS (including service packs) and then install them in order (2008, then 2008 SP, then 2010)